# How can we write Structures in file?

Tags: ios

I am new to IOS programming. I want to write a C style structure into file and retrieve back. 
I am able to write string into file after getting Document directory path. But how to write a structure in that file. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal C way of I\O operation worked well, however the to write file in particular location we need permission.

Answer (score 0):

You'd likely be most interested in the NSCoding protocol, as well as the Creating and Extracting Archives and Encoding and Decoding Objects in the [Archives and Serialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i) guide.

Comment: If it's just strings and numbers, a plist would be sufficient, written from resp. restored to a dictionary or array.